# How to format output for number of lines, words, characters for a file in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, wc

I am trying to write a shell script which will count the number of lines, words and characters in Bash.

```
    echo "Enter file name"
    read file
    if [ -f $file ]
    then
        echo "The number of lines in $file are "
        echo $(wc -l $file | cut -d " " -f1 )
    fi
```

The program does take the output but the cut part is not formatting the output. I checked the syntax for cut as well as wc. How do I get the number of lines without the filename at the end which is the default characteristic of the wc command?

This is the output I am getting now.

```
    Enter file name
    pow.sh
    The number of lines in pow.sh are
```

This is what is required.

```
    Enter file name
    pow.sh
    The number of lines in pow.sh are 3.
```

Comment: Add a number after `cut`'s option `-f`, e.g. `1`.

Comment: First, you're missing an argument to your `cut` command; `-f` takes a number to tell it what field to display.  Second, the output of `wc -l` starts with a number of space characters, each one of which is treated as a delimiter by `cut`.  You probably want to use `awk`  instead.

Comment: Oh. I actually had the argument while executing. Probably while pasting here, I missed it somewhere. I will edit the question. I need to use shell script specifically for this purpose. I can't be using awk.

Answer (score 2):

The typical way omit the filename is to avoid giving it to wc in the first place:

```
wc -l < $file
```

So you end up with:

```
printf "The number of lines in $file is "
wc -l < $file
```